# Cannot filter out NULL contains column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have joined 5 tables and I got the final result, this is the query given below.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT O.CUSTADDRESSID,
             O.ACCOUNTNO,
             O.ADDRESSTYPE,
             O.ADDRESSLINE1,
             O.ADDRESSLINE2,
             O.ADDRESSLINE3,
             O.CITY,
             O.STATE,
             O.COUNTRY,
             O.ZIP1,
             O.ISACTIVE AS ISACTIVE_ADDRESS,
             O.ISCOMMUNICATION AS ISCOMMUNICATION_ADDRESS,
             D.ORGANISATIONNAME,
             D.DATEOFINCORPORATION,
             D.PANCARDNUMBER,
             D.ORGANIZATIONTYPEID,
             P.CUSTMAILID,
             P.EMAILTYPE,
             P.EMAILADDRESS,
             P.ISACTIVE AS ISACTIVE_MAILID,
             P.ISCOMMUNICATION AS ISCOMMUNICATION_MAILID,
             Q.LOGINID,
             Q.USERNAME,
             Q.PASSWORD,
             Q.LAST_LOGINDATE,
             Q.LAST_PWD_MODIFIEDDATE,
             Q.CURRENT_PWD_EXPIRYDATE,
             Q.PWD_ATTEMPTS_COUNT,
             Q.PINNUMBER,
             Q.ISLOCKED,
             Q.THEMES,
             Q.LANGUAGES,
             Q.STATUSID,
             Q.USERTYPEID,
             Q.ROLENAME,
             Q.SQ_ATTEMPTCOUNT,
             Q.SQ_LOCKOUTTIME,
             R.CUSTPHONEID,
             R.PHONETYPE,
             R.PHONENUMBER,
             R.EXTENTION,
             R.ISACTIVE AS ISACTIVE_PHONES,
             R.ISCOMMUNICATION AS ISCOMMUNICATION_PHONES
      FROM ISSUER.TOLLPLUS.TP_CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES O
           FULL OUTER JOIN ISSUER.TOLLPLUS.TP_CUSTOMER_BUSINESS D ON O.ACCOUNTNO = D.ACCOUNTNO
           FULL OUTER JOIN ISSUER.TOLLPLUS.TP_CUSTOMER_EMAILS P ON D.ACCOUNTNO = P.ACCOUNTNO
           FULL OUTER JOIN ISSUER.TOLLPLUS.TP_CUSTOMER_LOGINS Q ON P.ACCOUNTNO = Q.ACCOUNTNO
           FULL OUTER JOIN ISSUER.TOLLPLUS.TP_CUSTOMER_PHONES R ON Q.ACCOUNTNO = R.ACCOUNTNO) A
GROUP BY CUSTADDRESSID,
         ACCOUNTNO,
         ADDRESSTYPE,
         ADDRESSLINE1,
         ADDRESSLINE2,
         ADDRESSLINE3,
         CITY,
         STATE,
         COUNTRY,
         ZIP1,
         ISACTIVE_ADDRESS,
         ISCOMMUNICATION_ADDRESS,
         ORGANISATIONNAME,
         DATEOFINCORPORATION,
         PANCARDNUMBER,
         ORGANIZATIONTYPEID,
         CUSTMAILID,
         EMAILTYPE,
         EMAILADDRESS,
         ISACTIVE_MAILID,
         ISCOMMUNICATION_MAILID,
         LOGINID,
         USERNAME,
         PASSWORD,
         LAST_LOGINDATE,
         LAST_PWD_MODIFIEDDATE,
         CURRENT_PWD_EXPIRYDATE,
         PWD_ATTEMPTS_COUNT,
         PINNUMBER,
         ISLOCKED,
         THEMES,
         LANGUAGES,
         STATUSID,
         USERTYPEID,
         ROLENAME,
         SQ_ATTEMPTCOUNT,
         SQ_LOCKOUTTIME,
         CUSTPHONEID,
         PHONETYPE,
         PHONENUMBER,
         EXTENTION,
         ISACTIVE_PHONES,
         ISCOMMUNICATION_PHONES
ORDER BY ACCOUNTNO;
```

4 result rows are given for example:

```
    CUSTADDRESSID   ACCOUNTNO   ADDRESSTYPE ADDRESSLINE1    ADDRESSLINE2    ADDRESSLINE3    CITY    STATE   COUNTRY ZIP1    ISACTIVE_ADDRESS    ISCOMMUNICATION_ADDRESS ORGANISATIONNAME    DATEOFINCORPORATION PANCARDNUMBER   ORGANIZATIONTYPEID  CUSTMAILID  EMAILTYPE   EMAILADDRESS    ISACTIVE_MAILID ISCOMMUNICATION_MAILID  LOGINID USERNAME    PASSWORD    LAST_LOGINDATE  LAST_PWD_MODIFIEDDATE   CURRENT_PWD_EXPIRYDATE  PWD_ATTEMPTS_COUNT  PINNUMBER   ISLOCKED    THEMES  LANGUAGES   STATUSID    USERTYPEID  ROLENAME    SQ_ATTEMPTCOUNT SQ_LOCKOUTTIME  CUSTPHONEID PHONETYPE   PHONENUMBER EXTENTION   ISACTIVE_PHONES ISCOMMUNICATION_PHONES
    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    VISHWAS ROADLINES BELGAUM   2009-04-01 00:00:00.000 AWBPK6828R  2103    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
CUSTADDRESSID   ACCOUNTNO   ADDRESSTYPE ADDRESSLINE1    ADDRESSLINE2    ADDRESSLINE3    CITY    STATE   COUNTRY ZIP1    ISACTIVE_ADDRESS    ISCOMMUNICATION_ADDRESS ORGANISATIONNAME    DATEOFINCORPORATION PANCARDNUMBER   ORGANIZATIONTYPEID  CUSTMAILID  EMAILTYPE   EMAILADDRESS    ISACTIVE_MAILID ISCOMMUNICATION_MAILID  LOGINID USERNAME    PASSWORD    LAST_LOGINDATE  LAST_PWD_MODIFIEDDATE   CURRENT_PWD_EXPIRYDATE  PWD_ATTEMPTS_COUNT  PINNUMBER   ISLOCKED    THEMES  LANGUAGES   STATUSID    USERTYPEID  ROLENAME    SQ_ATTEMPTCOUNT SQ_LOCKOUTTIME  CUSTPHONEID PHONETYPE   PHONENUMBER EXTENTION   ISACTIVE_PHONES ISCOMMUNICATION_PHONES
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    WHITEINK CONSULTANCY PRIVATE LIMITED    2013-08-27 00:00:00.000 AABCW4232E  3041    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
CUSTADDRESSID   ACCOUNTNO   ADDRESSTYPE ADDRESSLINE1    ADDRESSLINE2    ADDRESSLINE3    CITY    STATE   COUNTRY ZIP1    ISACTIVE_ADDRESS    ISCOMMUNICATION_ADDRESS ORGANISATIONNAME    DATEOFINCORPORATION PANCARDNUMBER   ORGANIZATIONTYPEID  CUSTMAILID  EMAILTYPE   EMAILADDRESS    ISACTIVE_MAILID ISCOMMUNICATION_MAILID  LOGINID USERNAME    PASSWORD    LAST_LOGINDATE  LAST_PWD_MODIFIEDDATE   CURRENT_PWD_EXPIRYDATE  PWD_ATTEMPTS_COUNT  PINNUMBER   ISLOCKED    THEMES  LANGUAGES   STATUSID    USERTYPEID  ROLENAME    SQ_ATTEMPTCOUNT SQ_LOCKOUTTIME  CUSTPHONEID PHONETYPE   PHONENUMBER EXTENTION   ISACTIVE_PHONES ISCOMMUNICATION_PHONES
1   10000000    Business    Madhapur    Mega Hils   NULL    Hyderbad    AP  IND 789564  1   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
CUSTADDRESSID   ACCOUNTNO   ADDRESSTYPE ADDRESSLINE1    ADDRESSLINE2    ADDRESSLINE3    CITY    STATE   COUNTRY ZIP1    ISACTIVE_ADDRESS    ISCOMMUNICATION_ADDRESS ORGANISATIONNAME    DATEOFINCORPORATION PANCARDNUMBER   ORGANIZATIONTYPEID  CUSTMAILID  EMAILTYPE   EMAILADDRESS    ISACTIVE_MAILID ISCOMMUNICATION_MAILID  LOGINID USERNAME    PASSWORD    LAST_LOGINDATE  LAST_PWD_MODIFIEDDATE   CURRENT_PWD_EXPIRYDATE  PWD_ATTEMPTS_COUNT  PINNUMBER   ISLOCKED    THEMES  LANGUAGES   STATUSID    USERTYPEID  ROLENAME    SQ_ATTEMPTCOUNT SQ_LOCKOUTTIME  CUSTPHONEID PHONETYPE   PHONENUMBER EXTENTION   ISACTIVE_PHONES ISCOMMUNICATION_PHONES
21  10000789    Business    IBTTA Interoperability          Plano   AP  IND 533126  1   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

But the `ACCOUNTNO` contains `NULL`.
I want to filter out the NULL values contains in `ACCOUNTNO` So I gave `WHERE ACCOUNTNO != NULL`but THE RESULT I AM GETTING NO VALUES, EMPTY ROWS

```
CUSTADDRESSID   ACCOUNTNO   ADDRESSTYPE ADDRESSLINE1    ADDRESSLINE2    ADDRESSLINE3    CITY    STATE   COUNTRY ZIP1    ISACTIVE_ADDRESS    ISCOMMUNICATION_ADDRESS ORGANISATIONNAME    DATEOFINCORPORATION PANCARDNUMBER   ORGANIZATIONTYPEID  CUSTMAILID  EMAILTYPE   EMAILADDRESS    ISACTIVE_MAILID ISCOMMUNICATION_MAILID  LOGINID USERNAME    PASSWORD    LAST_LOGINDATE  LAST_PWD_MODIFIEDDATE   CURRENT_PWD_EXPIRYDATE  PWD_ATTEMPTS_COUNT  PINNUMBER   ISLOCKED    THEMES  LANGUAGES   STATUSID    USERTYPEID  ROLENAME    SQ_ATTEMPTCOUNT SQ_LOCKOUTTIME  CUSTPHONEID PHONETYPE   PHONENUMBER EXTENTION   ISACTIVE_PHONES ISCOMMUNICATION_PHONES
```

Need Help. Thanks.

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server MS

Comment: I've edited your SQL so at least it's legible, however, that sample data isn't useful to anyone I'm afraid, and it's far too large for me to fix without spending some time on it.

Comment: This sample data is very useful. Might not be for you only. However it's done

Comment: HOw is the sample data useful? It's not even aligned properly... Unless you're saying that the value (on the first row) for `LAST_PWD_MODIFIEDDATE` is `NULL    NULL` (hmm, preformatted text in comments removes multiple spaces, didn't realise/know that).

Answer (score 4):

you can check null values with IS

```
WHERE ACCOUNTNO IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the OP's question, however, there no need to use a subquery here, nor that HUGE `GROUP BY` clause. Simply use `DISTINCT` ([Using DISTINCT with SELECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-examples-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-using-distinct-with-select)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       O.CUSTADDRESSID,
       O.ACCOUNTNO,
       O.ADDRESSTYPE,
       O.ADDRESSLINE1,
       O.ADDRESSLINE2,
       O.ADDRESSLINE3,
       O.CITY,
       O.STATE,
       O.COUNTRY,
       O.ZIP1,
       O.ISACTIVE AS ISACTIVE_ADDRESS,
       O.ISCOMMUNICATION AS ISCOMMUNICATION_ADDRESS,
       D.ORGANISATIONNAME,
       D.DATEOFINCORPORATION,
       D.PANCARDNUMBER,
       D.ORGANIZATIONTYPEID,
       P.CUSTMAILID,
       P.EMAILTYPE,
       P.EMAILADDRESS,
       P.ISACTIVE AS ISACTIVE_MAILID,
       P.ISCOMMUNICATION AS ISCOMMUNICATION_MAILID,
       Q.LOGINID,
       Q.USERNAME,
       Q.PASSWORD,
       Q.LAST_LOGINDATE,
       Q.LAST_PWD_MODIFIEDDATE,
       Q.CURRENT_PWD_EXPIRYDATE,
       Q.PWD_ATTEMPTS_COUNT,
       Q.PINNUMBER,
       Q.ISLOCKED,
       Q.THEMES,
       Q.LANGUAGES,
       Q.STATUSID,
       Q.USERTYPEID,
       Q.ROLENAME,
       Q.SQ_ATTEMPTCOUNT,
       Q.SQ_LOCKOUTTIME,
       R.CUSTPHONEID,
       R.PHONETYPE,
       R.PHONENUMBER,
       R.EXTENTION,
       R.ISACTIVE AS ISACTIVE_PHONES,
       R.ISCOMMUNICATION AS ISCOMMUNICATION_PHONES
FROM ISSUER.TOLLPLUS.TP_CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES O
     FULL OUTER JOIN ISSUER.TOLLPLUS.TP_CUSTOMER_BUSINESS D ON O.ACCOUNTNO = D.ACCOUNTNO
     FULL OUTER JOIN ISSUER.TOLLPLUS.TP_CUSTOMER_EMAILS P ON D.ACCOUNTNO = P.ACCOUNTNO
     FULL OUTER JOIN ISSUER.TOLLPLUS.TP_CUSTOMER_LOGINS Q ON P.ACCOUNTNO = Q.ACCOUNTNO
     FULL OUTER JOIN ISSUER.TOLLPLUS.TP_CUSTOMER_PHONES R ON Q.ACCOUNTNO = R.ACCOUNTNO
ORDER BY O.ACCOUNTNO;
```

Also, is the problem you're having due to you using `FULL OUTER JOIN`s? I wonder if your rows of `NULL` problem will go away if you use an `INNER JOIN`..?

Comment: You have to understand the requirement first, I cannot use inner join instead of full outer join as per the requirements.

Comment: @BhaskarDas Why is that a a requirement..? You don't mention it in your question (so how would the volunteers here know?). If you've got more requirements that you've told us about, why aren't you telling us about them?